# buildozer can't download webbrowser

Tags: android, python, kivy

I wanted to compile this, perfectly working, Program with buildozer:

```
import webbrowser

from kivy.app import App

class FAN(App):
    def build(self):
        webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.freies-aktivisten-netzwerk.de/wordpress/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FAN().run()

FAN().stop()`
```

Despite the fact, that I wrote the requirements in Buildozer, it did not work, and I got this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking random
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement random
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for random
Storing debug log for failure in /home/gilgamesch/.pip/pip.log
.# Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/home/gilgamesch/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/gilgamesch/games/.buildozer/applibs random
```

Comment: an python buildin module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

random and webbrowser are builtin modules, you should not include them in the requirements line. This line is only for external things that will be installed with pip, or internal/external things with a special recipe for their compiled components.